# Can you translate dynamic messages in new AngularJS i18n system (coming in 1.4)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, internationalization, translation

I am at the start of a new Angular project and is currently investigating how I am going to handle translations, both client side and server side.

I hear that AngularJS 1.4 will provide a new better 'angular' way of doing i18n but I cannot for the life of me find any really good documentation on it yet.

I understand that there is a lot of tooling for extracting text right out of the HTML files. However, what about text that is dynamically inserted from Javascript? Like error messages when an API call fails - or even error messages coming straight from the API?

This seems easy enough with angular-translate (having key-value translation), but since this is a new project, it seems like it's smart to go for the newest solution that is official supported (soon).

Am I thinking about this wrong? Should I even have dynamic messages from javascript? Should the server with the API be in charge of delivering a error messages that are properly translated?

I have watched: "Better i18n for your Angular apps Chirayu Krishnappa and Pascal Precht" and read the Developer Guide for "i18n and l10n" on the official site, but it doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new i18n solution is based on a pre compile step in order to make both, a client side but also server side solution, possible. At this time, application logic is not executed, so messages that come from the JavaScript world remain unknown by the localization process.

This means, all messages need to be available at compile time in the template, since that is the data we're relying on.

Bottom line: messages need to be where they belong to, the template, but can be conditionally displayed at runtime using directives like ng-if. E.g. error message here.